# typescript extension in VSCode

Tags: typescript, react-native, visual-studio-code

I just created a sample react-native project with the following command.

> `react-native init SampleProject --template typescript`

Then I got the red line of Editor. How to fix this?

I guess this concerns with extension.
What extension should I install for typescript in react-native?

[image]

This is the image that I hover mouse on  tag.
[image]

Comment: What does it say if you hover above the red lines?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I edited post. Please check the image.

Comment: This error should go away if you follow my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did the following and it worked for me.

`yarn add --dev @types/react-native`

Comment: Thanks. it worked. Then some red lines have gone, but some still remained.

Comment: @SatelBill, if you would install eslint with the right extensions, they will go away.

Comment: Installed ESLint also, But still remained. :(

Comment: For other packages try `@types/package-name` eg: `@types/react-redux`

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using ESLint

> Last year TSLint was deprecated in favor of ESLint (TSLint in 2019). TSLint was a valuable project for the TypeScript community and the efforts there were greatly appreciated. The migration from TSLint to ESLint is welcome in being able to leverage more of what the larger JavaScript community has been developing

In addition you should add `eslint-plugin-react-native` and `eslint-plugin-react` to your dev dependencies and inside `.eslintrc.js` (eslint config file) add to the `module.exports`

```
plugins: ['react', 'react-native']
```